# User rights in sitemap permissions in asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, sitemap

I have old complex project which includes user roles. In file Rights.sitemap I have code like this:

```
<Page url="~/Account/Account.aspx" rightsAny="OwnPesonalDetailesView, OwnPasswordChange" />
<Page url="~/Account/PersonalData/PersonalData.aspx" rightsAny="OwnPersonalDataChange, OwnPersonalDataChange" />
<Page url="~/Account/PasswordChange/PasswordChange.aspx" rightsAny="OwnPasswordChange" />
<Page url="~/Account/LoginHistory/LoginHistory.aspx" />
```

I am trying to understand what 'rightsAny' tag means in this context. I tried to google it but without success.
When I crtl+F and search for 'rightsAny' it only occurs in this .sitemap file.

Values after tag 'rightsAny' refer to RightNameValues.cs which code sample is below:

```
public const string OwnPasswordChange = "OwnPasswordChange";
public const string OwnPersonalDataChange = "OwnPersonalDataChange";
public const string OwnPesonalDetailesView = "OwnPesonalDetailesView";
public const string PartnersActivate = "PartnersActivate";
```

I can use this right in context like below:

```
if(Foo.Common.Application.AppContext.Current.Operator.HasRight(RightNameValues.OwnPasswordChange))
    {
        Label2.Text = "This user have rights to change password";
    }
```

But I tried all combination of setting line ex:

```
<Page url="~/Account/PasswordChange/PasswordChange.aspx" 
 rightsAny="OwnPasswordChange" />
```

and I do not see any changes on site PasswordChange.aspx.
Maybe some of you know anything about my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, the project implements a custom site map provider, which inherits from the [SiteMapProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sitemapprovider?view=netframework-4.8) class.

You may want to find the class of the custom provider (look inside the `App_Code` folder or the `web.config` for any added site map providers) and take a look at the overridden methods to discover the way your proprietary formatted .sitemap file is parsed.

This way you'll be able to understand the meaning of the `rightsAny` property.